# Android: Alignment text in button using setGravity()

Tags: android

I wolud like to set button's gravity value from default `center` to `right` using `TextView.setGravity()` method, but when I call it nothing happens. In LogCat output using `getGravity()` method I still see the first value - 17 (`center`).

Tell me please, how can I change button's gravity value, using `setGravity()` method?

Here is code snippet which describes setting the view's gravity:

```
public void setGravity(String gravitation) {
        if(controlledView != null) {
            String gravityValues[] = gravitation.split("|");
            for(String gravity : gravityValues) {
                if(gravity.equals("center")) {
                    controlledView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                }
                else if(gravity.equals("top")) {
                    controlledView.setGravity(Gravity.TOP);
                }
                else if(gravity.equals("bottom")) {
                    controlledView.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM);
                }
                else if(gravity.equals("right")) {
                    controlledView.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
                }
                else if(gravity.equals("left")) {
                    controlledView.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
                }
            }
        }
}
```

where `controlledView` is instance of `Button` class.

Comment: Please give some more information and code so we can help you.

Comment: Hi, everybody. The idea is that I need to avoid using XML code in my application so I need some solution how to change button's gravity directly in the code.

Answer (score 3):

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.mytextviewid);
textView.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
```

I'm assuming you weren't using `Gravity.RIGHT`; other valid values can be found in the [`Gravity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/Gravity.html) constants.

Comment: In fact of the matter that I used it. Besides I don't change `TextView` object, but `Button`

Answer (score 0):

I'm sory for this post, found my mistake myself. I pass to `split()` method `Java Regex API`'s metacharacter **'|'** and get all symbols of string. Should choose any other split symbols for string.

Answer (score -1):

You can use in XML layout's like > (RightClick->Properties->Gravity->"your option")